# How can I follow a Kickstarter backer?

Tags: kickstarter

On Kickstarter, I already have some friends that I am following, but I can't seem to remember how I added them in the first place. Now that I want to 'add', or 'follow' another Kickstarter backer/friend, there seems to be no way to add him, not even from his profile page.

I checked other backers' profile pages, and also the profiles of the people I'm already following, but there's simply nothing that lets me follow them.

Only on the 'manage friends' page, I can unfollow the people I already follow, but that's it.

Does anyone have an explanation for this, cause I'm out of ideas... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2016 Kickstarter [says the following at their website](https://www.kickstarter.com/friends):

> ... If you connect with Facebook, you can follow your friends to get notified as they’re backing and launching projects...

The only way you can add someone as a friend, is if they have connected their Kickstarter account and their Facebook account

Answer (score 0):

The next day, I got a mail from Kickstarter that my friend I was wanting to follow, had started following me. I checked with him, and coincidence or not, he only connected his Facebook account with his Kickstarter profile later that previous day.
Which leads me to believe that in order to follow your friends on Kickstarter, both of you must have connected your Facebook account.

At least that's my best guess, as Kickstarter doesn't provide further information on this.  Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but until then, I'll have to accept my own answer (again :().